# FuelUX Modal overriding Bootstrap Modals

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, fuelux

I am using fuelux 2.4.0 and Bootstrap 3.1.1.

I have used the code provided by Bootstrap to provide a popup modal;

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However the FuelUX CSS is being used, and it is making the popup all wrong and distorted.

Anyway to disgreard FuelUX and use the BS CSS instead?

Thanks

Comment: I've run into this same issue. FuelUX seems to have a pretty serious problem with CSS collisions. They provide no modal as part of their library, yet the FuelUX CSS overrides the BS modal. That's crap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it by removing `class="fuelux` from the body style :)